# add custom tab to magento product detail page

Tags: product

i want to add custom tab in frontend product detail pages, just next to short desc and want to show some content there, can i do this via

like detail, product tags, review, mycustom tab here

```
1: admin catalog > catagory custom design

2: via any module ?
```

i tried below code in custom layout update:

```
<action method="addTab" module="catalog" translate="title">
    <alias>info</alias>
    <title>Info</title>
    <block>catalog/product_view_attributes</block>
    <template>catalog/product/view/a.phtml</template>
</action>
```

Comment: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/easy-tabs-2-0-free-magento-extension.html for product page tab but you cant controll product tab from category layout

Comment: yeah but i want to learn how to do it now using any build in module

Comment: how i can add a class or id to new tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

app/design/frontend/default/yourtheme/layout -> catalog.xml in  section you need add:

```
<action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog">
    <alias>My New Custom Tab</alias>
    <title>My New Custom Tab</title>
    <block>core/template</block>
    <template>catalog/product/mynewcustomtab.phtml</template>
</action>
```

in mynewcustomtab.phtml you can output you info

Comment: but i do not want to do changes in code , can i do it via module or add custom design

Comment: i treid above code but i does not worked

Comment: above code is not working ???

Comment: what if i want to show it for configuravble products only ??.

Comment: can write the condition)

Comment: how should is ask new question for that , or can u write code here , ie update code