# Add tab in product edit page in magento2?

Tags: product, magento2.2, php-7

**How to create a Customtab( which contains grid) in product edit page (like product Review tab in product edit page)using php in magento2?**

Is there any possible?

Thanks

Comment: You can follow this https://webkul.com/blog/add-tab-product-page-magento-admin/

Comment: Is there any possible to create that in php(without uicomponent)

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/42678/69